# Translations of 你要的衣服还没买， 你要的旗袍呢 - New Practical Chinese Reader 2 Chap.17

Tags: translation, grammar

I am trying to translate the text of the new practical Chinese reader 2 chap 17, and I got stuck on the following two phrases
"你要的衣服还没买。" and "你要的旗袍呢？"
The context are two people buying clothes in a shop.
I have heard that the 的 particle can also be used for "adjective clauses", is this the case here?

I appreciate all the help.

Comment: "你要旗袍呢？" sounds odd. Are you sure it is not "你要(的)旗袍呢？", "你要旗袍呢(!)" , or "你要旗袍(嗎)?"

Comment: Yes, my apologies there is indeed a 的 that is missing. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 你要衣服 (noun + verb + object) = you need/ want clothes
- 你要旗袍 (noun + verb + object) = you need/ want cheongsam

The verb applies an action to the object

> I have heard that the 的 particle can also be used for "adjective clauses", is this the case here?

Yes, 的 turns the noun + verb phrase 你要 into an adjective phrase that describes the noun e.g. 衣服，旗袍

- **你要的**衣服 (adjective phrase + object) = the clothes **that you need / want**
- **你要的**旗袍 (adjective phrase + object) = the cheongsam **that you need/ want**
- 你要的衣服还没买 = the clothes that you need/ want hasn't been bought yet
- 你要的旗袍呢? = how about / where is the cheongsam that you need/ want?

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Tang Ho's comment hits the main problem of the second sentence. Here is the translation after correction:

You haven't purchased (chosen) the cloth you wanted yet. Where is the 旗袍 (traditional dress) you wanted?